# What is the XPath/regex for this text?

Tags: regex, xpath

I am learning, but I need to get the XPath or a regex for the paragraph text beneath "Education" header below.

When using XPath, the problem is, all the stuff about the "Education" header may have an unpredictable number of elements, paragraphs etc. That is, the stuff below "Education" may not always be at div/paragraph position X. But it WILL always be below the "Education" header.

Many thanks.

```
<div class="toggle_cls">
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
        <div class="bold" style="margin-top:20px;">Previous Work Experience</div>
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
        <div class="bold" style="margin-top: 20px;"><span class="bold">Education</span></div>
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div><span class="text_more hidden noDisp">(Read Full Bio)</span><span class="text_less hidden noDisp">(Less)</span><span class="text_charlength hidden noDisp">275</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is your actual html, xpath most likely will not work because you have an additional closing div at the end.

Comment: what do you mean by "may not always be at div/paragraph position X"? do you mean the index in the top level div, i.e. 4 (zero-based) in your example? if not, what else? maybe add another example to clarify what is and isn't known about the document structure

Comment: The previous commenters are right. In addition, please show what exactly the result should look like (show it as code, explanations are not clear enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath that looks for an element who's computed text is 'Education' and selects it's first following-sibling:

```
//*[.='Education']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is that purely an XPath or a combined XPath/regex?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with jquery, not very reliable, but can do the job.

```js
var education_tag= $('div:contains("Education")');
var p_tags= education_tag.nextAll('p');
console.log(p_tags);

var education_paragraph= '';
for( var i=0,len=p_tags.length;i<len;i++)
  education_paragraph+= p_tags[i].innerText+ " ";
console.log(education_paragraph);

var result_div= document.createElement("div");
result_div.innerHTML= education_paragraph;
result_div.id= "education_paragraph";
document.body.appendChild(result_div);
```

```css
#education_paragraph{
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  margin:2%;
  padding:1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="display:none">
  <div class="toggle_cls">
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
        <div class="bold" style="margin-top:20px;">Previous Work Experience</div>
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
        <div class="bold" style="margin-top: 20px;"><span class="bold">Education</span></div>
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div><span class="text_more hidden noDisp">(Read Full Bio)</span><span class="text_less hidden noDisp">(Less)</span><span class="text_charlength hidden noDisp">275</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @filburt Ignore that. Disregard everything from from span class "text_more hidden noDisp" to the end of the snippet. I pasted/indented incorrectly just for the purposes of this question. There is more code in the source material than just what you see, which is only a snippet. Thanks.